# php submit rating data without reload

Tags: php, ajax, return, rating

I'm working with joomla template which make me able to rate on some music album.
The problem is each time I press rating stars reload the page with damaged layout
I just need to submit the rating result without reload.
here are the code:

```
        if($album_id) {
            $image_attr = $image_attr_java;
            $return .= "<a href='".JURI::root(true)."/index.php?option=com_muscol&task=rate&album_id=$album_id&points=$i&type=album'>".JHTML::image('components/com_muscol/assets/images/star' . $grey.$show_small. '.png' , "$i ".JText::_('out of')." 5" , $image_attr )."</a>";
        } else {
            $return .= JHTML::image('components/com_muscol/assets/images/star' . $grey.$show_small. '.png' , "$points ".JText::_('out of')." 5" , $image_attr );
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript code?

Comment: you may go with the ajax request onClick of the stars

Comment: there are on top of code

Comment: You should use available components/plugin in joomla like this :http://www.aljextdev.com/en/news/1-joomla-15-extensions/52-al-ratings-component-v2-joomla16-released.html

Comment: function show_stars($points,$admin = false,$album_id = false,$ajax=false,$small=false){ but i did not know how to use it

Comment: look into the demo given in url I Gave you

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using a JavaScript library?

If you are generating html like this:

```
<a class="vote" href="...">Up vote!</a>
<a class="vote" href="...">Down vote!</a>
```

And you are using for example, jQuery - the following snippet:

```
$('a.vote').click(function(e) {
    $.get(this.attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Would make the call to your server without refreshing the page. That's the bare minimum of code, but gives you a starting point.

If you aren't using jQuery it's of course still possible to do the same, [it's just much more verbose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).